# yii-Unable to find the requested action

Tags: php, yii

Is there any setting for URL in YII, I am not getting out of this problem, every time I create a new action, it says **The system is unable to find the requested action** the requested action is present in that specific controller

Comment: what did you named that action exactly ?

Comment: createFeatured. my URL is like localhost/project/module/controller/action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name to `actionCreateFeatured`.

And you must access it like `localhost/project/controller/createFeatured`.

for the 2nd error (you are not permitted ...) :

do this in controller :

```
action function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('createFeatured'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: another error now you are not allowed to perform this action :/